# How to develop a approval workflow using microsoft office sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007, infopath, visual-studio-2008-sp1

im developing a documents approval work flow for the processes of requesting for the purchase of items to the my department at my university.
The request form has to be filled with relevant item name,specifications and quantity.
Then the request is directed to the Dean of the faculty for the approval.
Then it's directed to the Bursar of the Supply division. Bursar check the request against the allocated budget and approve or reject the request.
If it's approved it goes to a clerk for the further purchasing process.
I have very poor knowledge on sharepoint development.
I hope to use infopath to prepare the forms.
I want to develop this workflow as a custom workflow using VS 2008.
It should be able to notify the next assigned user to proceed with the tasks.
also should able to see the workflow history and generate reports according to the time taken to complete the workflow.

I need very clear guidelines to develop this workflow using moss 2007.
Please help me with this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Be sure to check out the demo videos in InfoPath's built-in "Help". There's a great section with several videos explaining how to implement a document review system.

Answer (score 0):

[SharePoint Server 2007 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=79) includes approval workflow source code (along with other workflow samples) - it's far from being perfect but it's a good starting point.